# How to check which elements were blocked by DansGuardian?

Tags: proxy, squid, dansguardian

I am using DansGuardian. However, when I am visiting fm.baidu.com, which running some AJAX and also Flash, and also loading lyrics, and also some audio files, the page is fine, but audio is not running at all.

My question is, how to know which elements were blocked, such as which Javascript file, or audio file itself, or anything? So that I can add them to the exception list.

Comment: I just found out it is caused by Squid, not DansGuardian. But I still haven't figured it out how to solve from Squid configuration.

Comment: The problem also exists in Polipo. I think it is related to the web proxy, once using the web proxy server, then the jQuery doesn't work as expected.